# Having some problems with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, python-idle

So heres my script:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))

pygame.display.set_caption('Doge Adventures')

gameexit = False

move_x = 300
move_y = 300
move_x_change = 0
move_y_change = 0 

while not gameexit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameexit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_x_change = -10 
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_y_change = 10

move_x += move_x_change

gameDisplay.fill(white)

pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [move_x, move_y, 10, 10])

pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

---

The problem is that when I run it, nothing happens, no errors. Just the idle pops up, but no window. I was wondering if there was anything wrong with my code. I'm running python 2.6 with pygame 2.6

Comment: Is the code you provide formatted exactly as in your text editor? If so, then you must indentate everything (but the last 2 lines) so they are inside the while loop.

Comment: *Exactly* how did you try to run your file? Also, remove 'quit()' at the end.  If you possibly can, upgrade to 2.7.10 or 3.4 or 3.5.  Many bugs have been fixed and many improvement made in 5+ years.

Answer (score 0):

As I said you need to indentate everything, but I found many problems in your code, here's a version I did out of it:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))

pygame.display.set_caption('Doge Adventures')

gameexit = False

move_x = 300
move_y = 300
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

while not gameexit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameexit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_x -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_x += 10                
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                move_y -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                move_y += 10


    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [move_x, move_y, 10, 10])

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I recommend you the Al Sweigart book of Python/Pygame. It's such a great book.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot, because now I understand the gist of what to include and what not to include into the main loop. I'll check out the Al Sweigart book.